# STM32 LCD Library Which Is Written By Me It Doesn't Work

Tags: c++, c, embedded, stm32, lcd

I have written an LDC driver for STM32f3xx. Wiring is correct but LCD doesn't work. LCD shows only white squares so I think data pins doesn't work correctly or there are logical error. I use char because data is 1 byte actually.

**Here are the function's tasks:**

- `fallingEdge()` : send to falling edge signal for the waking up LCD.
- `send4BitMode()` : LCD works in 4bit mode. So first of all, it will send MSB(4) bits to LCD. After, I use bitwise operator for shifting 4bit right so LSB(4) bits sent to LCD.
- `sendCommand()` : This function sends commands to LCD. (two times)
- `sendCharacter()` : This function sends characters to LCD. (two times)

Here is the lcd.h for prototype functions;

```
/*
 * lcd.h
 *  Created on: 1 Ara 2020
 *      Author: fatay
 */

/*
 * LCD Connection Pins for Using This Library
 * DataPin1  -> RB1
 * DataPin2  -> RB2
 * DataPin3  -> RB3
 * DataPin4  -> RB4
 * EPin      -> RB5
 * RSPin     -> RB6
 *
 */

#ifndef INC_LCD_H_
#define INC_LCD_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f3xx.h"

#define DataPin1 1
#define DataPin2 2
#define DataPin3 3
#define DataPin4 4
#define EPin     5
#define RSPin    6


void clearLCD(void);
void setCursorToFirstLine(void);
void setCursorToSecondLine(void);
void initLCD(void);
void writeLCD(char str);



#endif /* INC_LCD_H_ */
```

and this is the lcd.c file;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"
#include "lcd.h"

/*
 * LCD Connection Pins for Using This Library
 * DataPin1  -> RB1
 * DataPin2  -> RB2
 * DataPin3  -> RB3
 * DataPin4  -> RB4
 * EPin      -> RB5
 * RSPin     -> RB6
 *
 */


//for manipulating bits
#define SET_IF(expr)  ((expr) ? GPIO_PIN_SET : GPIO_PIN_RESET)
/*
 * We will be send falling edge signal
 * for waking up an LCD. So function
 * should be like this;
 *
 */

static void fallingEdge(void)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, EPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, EPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}

/*
 * We send parallel 4 bit data in two times.
 * We will be getting first four (LSB) bits and then
 * the second one (MSB) bits.
 */

static void send4BitMode(char data)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, DataPin4, SET_IF(data & 0x08));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, DataPin3, SET_IF(data & 0x04));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, DataPin2, SET_IF(data & 0x02));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, DataPin1, SET_IF(data & 0x01));

    fallingEdge();
    HAL_Delay(1);

}

static void sendCommand(char command)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, RSPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    send4BitMode(command >> 4);
    send4BitMode(command);
}

static void sendCharacter(char character)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, RSPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    send4BitMode(character >> 4);
    send4BitMode(character);
}


/*
 *
 * USER SCOPE
 *
 */



void clearLCD(void) {
    sendCommand(0x01);
}

void setCursorToFirstLine(void)
{
    sendCommand((char) 0x80);
}

void setCursorToSecondLine(void)
{
    sendCommand((char) 0x40);
}

void initLCD(void)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, EPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, RSPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    sendCommand((char) 0x20 | 0x00 | 0x08);
    HAL_Delay(5);

    clearLCD();
    setCursorToFirstLine();
    HAL_Delay(500);
}

void writeLCD(char str)
{
    sendCharacter(str);

}
```

thanks for your interest .

Comment: It would be useful to specify the LCD device you are using.  And simply stating "it doesn't work" makes the question far too broad and little more than a code review.  What debugging have you done, what debug support do you have (debugger, test equipment such as a n oscilloscope for example).  I would suggest that the software is in error is more likely that "pins don't work" but if it is a hardware issue it is no an SO question.

Comment: `sendCommand()` and `sendCharacter()` are identical.  Is that correct? If so why do you need two separate functions?  If you do want two separate function and they are identical have one call the other or define a common `sendByte()` that they both call.

Comment: `writeLCD()` takes a _single character_  parameter, but the parameter name suggests you intended a string.  Without an example of usage, we cannot tell which part of this we should be looking at.  Presumably you are calling `initLCD()` and that is not working?  That information would narrow the question to just the initialisation - there may be other issues, but that would make the question too broad (it is too broad).  That is debugging that you should already have performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to do something like that:

```
static void send4BitMode(char data)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, EPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1);
    // delay of 100 MicroSec on my side

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, DataPin4, SET_IF(data & 0x08));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, DataPin3, SET_IF(data & 0x04));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, DataPin2, SET_IF(data & 0x02));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, DataPin1, SET_IF(data & 0x01));

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, EPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
```

}

Have a look to https://www.waveshare.com/datasheet/LCD_en_PDF/LCD1602.pdf
12. INITIALIZATION SEQUENCE, the sequence is:

```
void initLCD(void)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, EPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, RSPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    // The RW pin must be low

    send4BitMode((char) 0x03);
    // wait 4.1 ms

    send4BitMode((char) 0x03);
    // wait 100 us

    send4BitMode((char) 0x03);

    send4BitMode((char) 0x02); // set interface to 4 bit

    sendCommand( 0x28 ); // 0x20: Function set, 0x08: 2 lines

    ...
```

}

Comment: Yes, actually initilization is wrong. Thanks for answering. I use this initialization and problem was solved.